# Execução de query após alguns segundos

Tags: php, sql-insert, contador

tenho um script que registra todas as visualizações das páginas do meu site que bolei, e está funcionando muito bem.
Só que agora surgiu alguns problemas no que se trata de visitação do GOOGLE, e tem "muita", mais "muita" visitação dos Robôs do Google e não está legal para ter uma base de visitação do WebSite.

```
$db->query( "INSERT INTO visitas (ip_address,page_location,date_visitation,visitor_browser,visitor_plataform,visitor_city,visitor_region,visitor_country) VALUES ('$ip','$page_location','$date_visitation','$visitor_browser','$visitor_plataform','$visitor_city','$visitor_region','$visitor_country')" )->fetchAll();
```

Até onde sei, o robô do google não passa mais do que 5 segundos em uma página do site.

Eu gostaria de fazer este INSERT ser executado após 10 ou 15 segundos. Seria possível? ou teria uma outra solução para esta situação?

Grato pelo apoio.

EDIT 1

Surgiu a necessidade de **somente a function  setCounterVisitor()** ser executada após 15 segundos, devido meu script ser requerido em outra página. 
É importante que para funcionar a function ela venha está na mesma página e não no visitor.php.

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/visitor.php'; 
setCounterVisitor();
?>
```

É possível executar o  **setCounterVisitor();** após 15 segundos na página carregada?

Comment: coloque o código num arquivo php e chame ele com ajax, nesse ajax faça um `setTimeou`

Comment: Poderia me da um exemplo? o código já está em um arquivo PHP separado. Ele estou chamando em um requere_once.

Comment: Talvez a pergunta seja "como identificar os robôs de Google, Bing etc ?"

Answer (score 0):

Chame uma função dentro do `setTimeout`, passando o tempo de delay que ela deve ter (em milisegundos), essa função fará uma chamada assíncrona ao arquivo php que executará o insert

```
setTimeout(function() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'nomedoarquivo.php');
    httpRequest.send();
}, 15000);
```

Se já você estiver usando JQuery no seu código pode usar sua função de [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Outra opção é a api do [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

---

Não tenho certeza se é isso que quer mas você pode passar uma variável pela url e no visitor.php verificar se ela existe, se sim executa a função

No javascript altere a url do xhr:

```
httpRequest.open('GET', 'visitor.php?exe=true');
```

No php verifica se existe e chama a função:

```
if($_GET["exe"]) {
    setCounterVisitor();
}
```

Comment: Muito bom! Deu certo. Só que agora surgiu uma nova surpresa no meu script. É possível fazer isso para executar uma function em php com esse mesmo método? Tendo em vista que a function que É "setCounterVisitor()" deve ser executada na mesma página e não pegando por meio de um url. Tem possibilidade?

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta com um exemplo? Não entendi muito bem

Comment: Editei, veja por favor !

Comment: Editei a resposta veja se resolve o problema

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro quando executa o $_GET["exe"] do setCounterVisitor(); ----- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function setCounterVisitor() in C:\AppServ\www\site\header.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\AppServ\www\site\paginas\principal.php(16): include() #1 C:\AppServ\www\site\index.php(16): include('C:\\AppServ\\www\\...') #2 {main} thrown in

Comment: A função `setCounterVisitor` não existe no arquivo php chamado no XHR ou está dentro de uma classe, importe a função com o `require` ou instancie a classe e chame a função pela sua instância